# not working response.end() in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

According to knowledge of mine, the `response.end()` should be called in after every response according to the nodejs api documenetation it which is described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback).

But when I call the `response.end()` it will not load the html file to the browser.

Here is my code :

```
var http=require('http');
var fs=require('fs');

http.createServer(creatingRequest).listen(8000);
console.log("connected to the server");

function printMe(response) {

    response.writeHead(404,{"Context-Type":"text/plain"});
    response.write("this has  errors ");
    response.end();
    console.log("finished "+response.finished);//true if response ended
    console.log("printMe");

}

function creatingRequest(request,response) {



  if ((request.url=="/" ) && request.method=="GET")
  {

    response.writeHead(200,{"context-type":"text/html"});
    fs.createReadStream("./index.html").pipe(response);

    console.log("loading html");
    response.end();
    console.log("finished "+response.finished);//true if response ended
  }
  else
  {

     printMe(response);
  }

}
```

But ,if it runs the `printMe()` function ,then the "**this has errors**" text will be appear on the browser.

Here is my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    Hi,this is my page
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're not even sending your response, you're only ending the connection, if you want to write to the page, you should use `response.send()`

Comment: @Roljhon: i have send the response using the `response.writeHead() `method as a html file,isn't it?

Comment: if you're doing it on that way, the below would rectify the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should end the response, when the stream is read/written completely to the response.

e.g. you can listen for `end` event on stream and can fire `resp.end()` in it.

```
if ((request.url=="/" ) && request.method=="GET"){
   response.writeHead(200,{"context-type":"text/html"});
   var stream = fs.createReadStream("./index.html");

   stream.pipe(response);

   stream.on('end', function(){
      console.log("loading html");
      response.end();
      console.log("finished "+response.finished);//true if response ended
   });
}
```

Comment: yes,it works well.but what is this `stream.on()`? why can't we end the response without using it

Comment: `stream.on()` is event listener for stream object. Whenever stream finishes read/writing the data, it fires `end` event. It is the right place to end the response, else you will close the response before finishing piping the stream data to response. This is default async behaviour of node.js

Comment: thanks a lot ,just needed to clarify the answer well.